# Prevent animated background image in pseudo ::before element from being cropped

Tags: jquery, html, css, animate.css

I am trying to have the background image of a div animate in scale and rotation, and have semi-achieved this using a pseudo ::before element of the div, and having the background image on that element. The problem is that I can't seem to get the text in the orginal div to present in front of the animated background, and also i am having weird issues with the graphic being cropped to the dimensions of the final div size.

Its hard to explain but you can more easily see in my [demonstration jsfiddle here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/unhbwmcg/)

**Here is my html:**

```
<body>
<div id="box">
<h1>I want this title to stay in the foreground</h1>   
</div>
</body>
```

And here is my css:

```
body {
background-color:#333;
}

#box {
z-index:2;
width:700px;
height:200px;
border:3px solid #e7f26d;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
color:#000;
}

#box * {
z-index:2;
}

#box::before {
content:"";
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
background-image:url('https://www.picpng.com/image/view/110525');
background-image:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
-webkit-animation:grow-rotate 4s linear normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow-rotate { 
0% {transform: rotate(320deg) scale(0);}
100% {transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.2);} 
}
```

**The multiple problems i am trying to solve are:**

**1. MAIN PROBLEM** Prevent the background graphic form being cropped. The image is a
    spiral/circular, and i want to see the full spiral until it reaches
    the edges of its parent. So, ultimately it does get cropped when it
    reaches the container div boundaries, but not whilst it's scaling
    up. Is this even possible? I have tried various combinations of
    overflow properties, but i must have position:relative on the #box
    div.

**2.** Does the final degree of rotation have to be its finishing
    point? i only want to turn the image about 40 degrees from start to
    finish, but i don't want a sudden jump at the end to its starting
    point, hence why i start the rotation at 320deg and finish at
    360deg, so there isn't a sudden jump at the end. Albeit this isn't
    working here either.For some reason its jumping at the end to full scale.

**3.** keep the h1 title text in front of the background graphic

Apologies if this is too many problem points for one question. Number 1 is my primary problem right now. Thank you to anyone who may be able to help me figure some of this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

**Cropping Issue**:

Try to make the `:before` element to square using `top` and `bottom` negative values and use `background-size:contain`(It will remove your cropping issue)

**Heading Issue**:

Set `z-index:-1` to the `:before` pseudo class.

**Jumping Issue**

Set your `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

***[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/unhbwmcg/49/)***

Comment: Oh wow. Suddenly so beautiful. thank you! :) 

May i ask a couple of questions: 

1) how did you decide on the size to make the square? was it based on eth size of my PNG image? 

2) I see you changed the final state of the scale to a complete full scale (1). What if i only want the final scale to be 0.5, when i do this, it always suddenly jumps to full scale at the end. Do you know why?

Comment: @user2998925 1)square: because your block have width 700px so I made the `:before` to 700px in height...2)..if you want your scale value to change other than 1 you have to change your animation-direction:forwards which is normal now....Updated to scale(0.5) and direction forwards.....check updated fiddle...

Comment: amazing - THANK YOU! and one final question... what if the width of my #box div is dynamic (a row in bootstrap), how would i know what negative margin to give?

Comment: @user2998925 set top and bottom value higher to -99999px....and apply `backgound-position: center center` so that your background always stay at center...

Comment: Thanks so much Bhuwan for your help. I greatly appreciate it!